# mgcv GAM - is it possible to include the 'simple' product of two 1-d smooths?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, functional-data-analysis

I am trying to test out various `mgcv::gam` models in a scalar-on-function regression analysis.

The following is the 'hierarchy' of models I would like to test:
$$
Y_i = \alpha + \int_0^TX_i(t)\beta(t) dt \tag{1}
$$

$$
Y_i = \alpha + \int_0^TF(X_i(t))\beta(t) dt \tag{2}
$$

$$
Y_i = \alpha + \int_0^TF(X_i(t),t) dt \tag{3}
$$

where $Y_i$ are scalar outcomes for the $i$th subject, and $X_i(t)$ is a functional covariate observed at times $t\in[0,1,...T]$.  Intuitively, model 1 is a linear functional model with a (potentially non-linear) time-dependent regression coefficient for the covariate.  Model 2 allows for a non-linear weight function for the covariate, but which is constant over time.  Model 3 is the full 'functional GAM' that allows for a fully flexible non-linear covariate- and time- dependent function.  In my mind at least these form a natural step-by-step approach to testing this type of regression model.

Models 1 (linear functional) and 3 (functional GAM) are relatively straightforward to do with matrix arguments to `mgcv::gam`.  Assume $N$ subjects observed at $T$ time points.  `Y` is the length $N$ vector of scalar outcomes and `X`,`T`, `W` are the $N\times T$ matrices of the functional predictor data values, their observation times, and trapezoidal quadrature weights, respectively.

Models (1) and (3) could be obtained with:

```
m1 = gam(Y ~ s(T, by=I(X*W), bs='ps')
m3 = gam(Y ~ te(X, T, by=W), bs='ps')
```

However, I cannot find a way to achieve model (2)?  Effectively what I need (I think) is a way of creating a `te()` tensor product smooth but somehow constraining each marginal smooth to be the same for all values of the other variable?  Is this possible?

Comment: Reading the following, it doesn't look like the m3 model is right
https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/issues/346